# Intuition behind showing $AA^{-1}$ is zero off the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working through lecture notes for revision and I've come across this theorem and its proof.

> **Theorem.** An $n\times n$ matrix A is invertible if and only if $\det A \ne 0$.

In the proof of $\det A \ne 0$ implies $A$ invertible, we define $D$ by the formula for the inverse, then aim to prove $AD = DA = I_n$. We show for $k = 1, \ldots, n$, $(AD)_{kk} = 1$.

Then, we need to show if $k \ne l$ then $(AD)_{kl} = 0$. We have the line
$$
(AD)_{kl} = \frac 1 {\det A}\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ki} (-1)^{i+l}\det \tilde A_{li}.
$$
Then, my lecturer claims that the above summation is equal to the determinant of the matrix,
$$\begin{pmatrix}A_{11} &\cdots & A_{1n}\\ 
\vdots &\ddots&\vdots \\ 
A_{k1} &\cdots & A_{kn}\\
\vdots &\ddots&\vdots \\  
A_{k1} &\cdots & A_{kn}\\
\vdots &\ddots&\vdots \\  
A_{n1} &\cdots & A_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

This is the step I don't fully understand. My lecturer said, and it is apparent, that the summation is *almost* the definition of a determinant. However, why is it the determinant of this matrix above?

Comment: Whats your definition of $A^{-1}$? If its the matrix such that $A^{-1}A = A A^{-1} = I$, then the result is trivial. Also, $D$ is normally used for diagonal matrix; i wouldn't use it in the way you're using it.

Comment: @Batman I used $AA^{-1}$ in the title for simplicity. The question actually concerns $AD$ with $D$ as defined here. I didn't know $D$ had a common meaning. I was just going off my lecture notes, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of it being a definition, but I guess you have seen the cofactor expansion of a determinant: By expanding $\det M$ along row $l$ we have
$$\det M = \sum_{i=1}^n M_{li} (-1)^{i+l} \det(\tilde M_{li}).$$

Now let $M$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing row $l$ with row $k$ (which I guess is what is meant by the matrix you show). Then on one hand, $\det M = 0$ because it has two identical rows. On the other hand, $M_{li} = A_{ki}$, and $\tilde M_{li} = \tilde A_{li}$ because $M$ and $A$ become the same after deleting row $l$, so the above sum is the same as the sum in the expression for $(AD)_{kl}$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.